# How to use the Rule class in scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to use the Rule class to go to the next page in my crawler. Here is my code

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from crawler.items import GDReview


class GdSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "gd"
    allowed_domains = ["glassdoor.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Johnson-and-Johnson-Reviews-E364_P1.htm"
    ]

    rules = (

        # Extract next links and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href',)), follow= True)
    )


    def parse(self, response):
        company_name = response.xpath('//*[@id="EIHdrModule"]/div[3]/div[2]/p/text()').extract()

        '''loop over every review in this page'''
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="EmployerReviews"]/ol/li'):
            review = Item()
            review['company_name'] = company_name
            review['id'] = str(sel.xpath('@id').extract()[0]).split('_')[1] #sel.xpath('@id/text()').extract()
            review['body'] = sel.xpath('div/div[3]/div/div[2]/p/text()').extract()
            review['date'] = sel.xpath('div/div[1]/div/time/text()').extract()
            review['summary'] = sel.xpath('div/div[2]/div/div[2]/h2/tt/a/span/text()').extract()

            yield review
```

My question is about the rules section. In this rule, the link extracted doesn't contain the domain name. For example, it will return something like
"/Reviews/Johnson-and-Johnson-Reviews-E364_P1.htm"

How can I make sure that my crawler will append the domain to the returned link?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can be sure since this is the default behavior of link extractors in Scrapy ([source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c9d7386a32aeb4bc7fe9654d194651eee1ede56c/scrapy/contrib/linkextractors/sgml.py#L41)).

Also, the `restrict_xpaths` argument should not point to `@href` attribute, but instead it should either point to `a` elements or containers having `a` elements as descendants. Plus, `restrict_xpaths` can be defined as string.

In other words, replace:

```
restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href',)
```

with:

```
restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="next"]/a'
```

---

Besides, you need to switch to `LxmlLinkExtractor` from [`SgmlLinkExtractor`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml):

> SGMLParser based link extractors are unmantained and its usage is
>   discouraged. It is recommended to migrate to LxmlLinkExtractor if you
>   are still using SgmlLinkExtractor.

Personally, I usually use the `LinkExractor` shortcut to `LxmlLinkExtractor`:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
```

---

To summarize, this is what I would have in `rules`:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="next"]/a'), follow=True)
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "plus, restrict_xpaths can be defined as string." ?? They have to be valid xpaths right?